# filter() method is not returning any results despite callbackFn does work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vuejs3

I have built a function which should filter some json elements in an array. I'm using Vue 3.

The data structure looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "UID_Person": "160a5b9e-c352-39e3-802b-9cfcc126da77",
        "FirstName": "Maxi",
        "LastName": "Mustermensch"
    },
    {
        "UID_Person": "268b3627-b9ea-3181-bd3c-17635c7d4a7e",
        "FirstName": "Chris",
        "LastName": "Mustermenschen"
    },
    {
        "UID_Person": "8e7344c3-02af-3029-9436-38c83019f34b",
        "FirstName": "Max",
        "LastName": "Mustermann"
    },
    {
        "UID_Person": "9dab6de1-927f-3ebb-a6ea-823a12d04442",
        "FirstName": "Hans",
        "LastName": "Muster"
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
<script>
some imports...

export default {
    setup() {
        const jsonDataPersons = ref({})
        const filterText = ref(new String)

        onBeforeMount(some API call saving data into jsonDataPersons...)

        const goToPerson = (uid) => {
            some code...
        }

       const filteredPerson = computed( () => {
            var filter = filterText.value;
            if (!filter.length) { return jsonDataPersons.value }

            return jsonDataPersons.value.filter(
                (person) => { 
                    //console.log(person)
                    //console.log(person.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
                    person.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) 
                }
            )
        }
       )

        return { goToPerson, jsonDataPersons, filterText, filteredPerson }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my html part:

```
<template>
    <main>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="title-page">Person List</h1>
            <div class="wrapper-list">
                <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for person..." v-model="filterText"/>
                <div class="list-item" @click="goToPerson(person.UID_Person)" v-for="person in filteredPerson" >
                    {{ person.FirstName }} {{ person.LastName }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

Everything works except when I'm filtering the data within `jsonDataPersons` using the `computed` function. I should be able to type my search string via the input tag and then filter the elements. The search string seems to be passed correctly.

Therefore, my problem seems to be the `filter()` function itself but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The callback function inside the filter methode seems also to be working. It gives back true or false correctly. In order to verify that I logged the piece of code in the console (it is commented out in the code). Still, filter() is not returning anything back. What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your callback _doesn't_ work, it always returns `undefined`. Also note a [mre] includes no Vue at all, just vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with return in your filter function:

```
return jsonDataPersons.value.filter(
  (person) => { 
    return person.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) 
})
```

or:

```
return jsonDataPersons.value.filter(
  person => person.FirstName.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) 
)
```